# Visual studio suppress error on undefined SASS variable

Tags: visual-studio, sass, visual-studio-2017, scss-mixins

I'm trying to suppress a specific error that is related to a SASS file in Visual Studio. I'll mention that **everything works great**, the CSS file is generated exactly as the SASS files should generate it, and even with this error on VS, so I think maybe it's a bug on VS.

Basically what I'm doing is that I have 2 SASS files that I declare some variables in them as settings for another SASS file that contains some mixins that work according to the settings file that provided in the context.

For exmaple, these are the 2 files for the settings:

***_settings-ltr.scss***

```
$bi-app-left: left;
$bi-app-right: right;
```

***_settings-rtl.scss***

```
$bi-app-left: right;
$bi-app-right: left;
```

And this is the file that uses those settings:

***_mixins.scss***

```
@mixin padding-left($distance) {
  padding-#{$bi-app-left}: $distance;
}

@mixin padding-right($distance) {
  padding-#{$bi-app-right}: $distance;
}
```

Now, basically the error says that the variable "$bi-app-left" is undefined (and "$bi-app-right" as well), and I'm really not defining these variables in the "_mixins.scss" file, I pass them to the context in some other SASS file, like this:

***site.scss***

```
@import '_settings-ltr.scss';
@import '_mixins.scss';
```

And **it works great**, except that error from VS:

[image: The error in Visual Studio]

**My Question**

How can I disable this error specifically, without disabling other SASS file errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how the VS SCSS editor resolves variables.  It does so from the perspective of the file being edited; because the SCSS editor instance for `_mixins.scss` does not know how the imports are resolved in `site.scss`, it doesn't have a way to resolve this reference.  If `_mixins.scss` had an @import chain up to the `_settings-ltr.scss` (or `-rtl`), then it would be able to resolve the variable and the error wouldn't be shown.

Similar feedback has been raised [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/189386/non-sass-scss-support.html) as well.  It would be worth opening a new feedback item to better describe the scenario (and also what you're using to compile SCSS, e.g. if you're using WebPack) so the team can prioritize this as a design change.  It won't get addressed right away, but we do take the number of feedback items into account for prioritizing the backlog. <sup>(And I'd love to have more ammunition to make this feature a priority...)</sup>

Currently, there isn't a way in VS to disable a specific SCSS error.  This could be another feature request, but it would be a low priority to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I have activated intellisense for files declared elsewhere by referencing the main file (i'll name it mainfile at my example) that imports all the other using `/// <reference path="./../mainfile" />`.

The code should change depending on the nesting of the mainfile (replace with the name of your own starting file that imports everything else).
Also the difference between the scss file you are adding it. For instance for two folders deep `./..` for three `../..` and so on.

Another example. I usually name my starting file main and all scss files are two - three folder deep.

```
../../main
./../main
```

Sadly i did not find a dynamic way to reference the path based on unknown members of files. Also that line has to be added to every single file.

The solution above offers intellisense which sorts the error and you can see the values on hover, go to definition etc as well.

Comment: Where do I put this line? In the SCSS file it does nothing.

Comment: Updated my answer @O.Shai

Comment: Thanks, as you said, it only suppressed the warnings and intellisense which is nice, but the real problem is still there, the error is not being suppressed, and this is not the solution for me.

Comment: It offers intellisense while typing & by going to definition etc as well.